# vb .net login and popup simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, popup, submit

ok im reposting this question cause i got some off track answers last time.
I have 3 aspx pages - page1, login and page3. Now when i goto login page from page1, after i login and goto page3 i should be able to open a popup on that submit and the login should change to page3. but if i goto login page directly, the popup should not open and the login will goto page3 as normal design. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx).  This will contain the Url for the page the user was on just before they came to this page.  If the UrlReferrer is NOT page1, then do not show the popup.

Comment: so where should this code be. I mean in what page? login or page1?

Comment: Since login is the page where the popup is opened, it should go there.  That way, if the user goes directly to login, without going first to page1, you'll know it.